# No se puede ejecutar un paquete SSIS desde vb6

Tags: c#, vb6, ssis

Estoy tratando de ejecutar un `paquete SSIS` desde `vb6`. Desde `c#` puedo ejecutar el paquete si utilizo el siguiente App.config :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <configuration>
   <startup>
     <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
   </startup>
</configuration>
```

El error que se produce desde `vb6` o `c#` si no modifico el `App.config` es el siguiente:

> The Execute method on the task returned error code 0x80131621 (Mixed mode assembly is built against version 'v2.0.50727' of the runtime and cannot be loaded in the 4.0 runtime without additional configuration information.). The Execute method must succeed, and indicate the result using an "out" parameter.

Pero cómo hago para ejecutarlo desde `vb6`?

Este es mi código en `vb6`:

```
pkgLocation = "c:\Package.dtsx"
  Set dtsApp = New Application


  Set package = dtsApp.LoadPackage(pkgLocation, True, Nothing)
  Set pkgContainer = package

  pkgResults = package.Execute

  If (pkgResults = 0) Then
   MsgBox "Success"
  Else
    MsgBox "Fail"
  End If
```

Gracias por su ayuda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontré una solución en el siguiente post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/175983/using-app-config-with-interop-controls

En resumen, si mi aplicación vb6 se llama vb6.exe , tengo que tener un archivo app.config con el nombre vb6.exe.config en el mismo directorio donde se encuentra el vb6.exe

Espero ayude a alguien.